# Cookies with extensions

Tags: php, cookies

I've seen cookies set by web pages with the "." character in them.  I'm trying to maximize the dynamic use of a $_GET['url'] to set my cookies, and then include it in a next page as a conditional where it checks to make sure the cookie was set before it allows users to perform an action.  Basically I'm using cookies and IP addresses in an anonymous voting action to make sure anyone who votes only gets one per day.  IPs are reset through a cron job once a day, and the cookies are set to expire after 17 hours.  I have no issues setting a cookie named with the .php extension, however after many hours of trial and error, I can't get it to accept it in an if(isset).  No matter what I try, it will not recognize that the cookie is set.  Without the extension everything works fine.  I've tried a dozen configurations, but here's basically what I have trying to debug.

```
<?php

$cookie = "test.php";
setcookie("$cookie", "workdamnyou");

if (isset($_COOKIE[$cookie])) {
echo "is set";
}
else {
echo "not set";
}
?>
```

I've tried isset($_COOKIE["$cookie"]) and isset($*COOKIE['$cookie']) as well.  That said, I really wish you could run PHP without uploading it each time to your server.. -*-

Comment: _"That said, I really wish you could run PHP without uploading it each time to your server"_. You should develop locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found the solution I guess... PHP doesn't like dots in variable names (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). Now, since Register Globals could be on, it might be possible that a $_COOKIE["name.ext"] could turn into a $name.ext which would be invalid. Thus, "Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example  becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"]." (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php).  Does a check for isset("name_php") work?

Comment: YES!!  Something so simple..  And the bad part?  I knew the underscore rule for variables.  I just didn't know it would be handled that way.  Thank you SO very much!  I'd have spent a month figuring that out! =D  If I could uprate you I would! lol

Comment: Thanks :) And well, I must admit that I learned something today as well :-) So also thanks for the question and glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

[setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) doesn't change $_COOKIE immediately. It sets the headers to change the cookie in the browser, so the script won't see the test value until you refresh the page.

You CAN run PHP without uploading to a server; the easiest option is to install a xAMP stack (LAMP/MAMP/WAMP depending on if you're developing on Linux/Mac/Windows).

Comment: Yes, I refresh after the initial setting of it.  And thank you for pointing me to that!  Notepad++ and Filezilla makes it not THAT bad, but that's going to save me a lot of time for bigger projects!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set and access a cookie in the same instance! You have to do a [redirect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), refresh or something, but you cannot both set and access at the same time. Also make sure your other parameters are set like hostname, expiry time. . e.t.c

Eg.

```
setcookie("TestCookie", $value, time()+3600, "/", "/", 1);
```

For debugging, just do a `var_dump($_COOKIE)`

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that.  The real script I am using sets it on one page, then uses the if(isset()) in a following page.  What I'm saying is everything works fine until I add the .php to the cookie name.  It sets it fine, but fails to recognize that it's been set in the if(isset()) conditional, only with the .php extension. =)  BTW that script works without the .php after you reload the page.  I'm just using that short script trying to find a way that it recognizes it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that cookies only become available on the next pageload (when they have traversed from server to client and back).

Try setting the cookie directly with $_COOKIES["test.php"] = "test"; and see what happens with

```
var_dump($_COOKIE);
```

Also don't use the quotes around the $cookie variable. Thus make it

```
setcookie($cookie, "work");
```

instead of

```
setcookie("$cookie", "work");
```

Last, you can run PHP locally with your own server. The easiest way on Windows is the WAMPP stack. I find this one very easy to install and run: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html

Good luck!

Comment: The var_dump returned it in the array list, but it doesn't help because I can't use it in the isset function and it just throws up a syntax error.  It's so odd..  I've been playing off and on with this for days.  The site's up and working fine, I just want to close this security loophole for people who turn cookies off and try to run through proxies to vote a bunch of times.  Or at least make it harder for them to cheat.  For some reason adding a decimal point to the cookie name is being a pain trying to find a way to check if it's set that works.  And thanks for the link!  I'm d/l now! :D

Comment: Well, I found something else which might be a hint... PHP doesn't like dots in (incoming) variable names (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php). For example, "Dots and spaces in variable names are converted to underscores. For example <input name="a.b" /> becomes $_REQUEST["a_b"]." (http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) But oh well, I don't know if that is of any help... :) Does a check for isset("name_php") work?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you have a `.php` extension in the cookie name? It should be:

```
$cookie = 'test';
```

See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt point 4.1:

The two state management headers, Set-Cookie and Cookie, have common

> syntactic properties involving attribute-value pairs.  The
> following    grammar uses the notation, and tokens DIGIT (decimal
> digits) and    token (informally, a sequence of non-special, non-white
> space    characters) from the HTTP/1.1 specification [RFC 2068] to
> describe    their syntax.
>
> av-pairs        =       av-pair *(";" av-pair)
>
> av-pair         =       attr ["=" value]        ; optional value
>
> attr            =       token
>
> value           =       word
>
> word            =       token | quoted-string
>
> Attributes (names) (attr) are case-insensitive.  White space is
> permitted between tokens.  Note that while the above syntax
> description shows value as optional, most attrs require them.
>
> NOTE: The syntax above allows whitespace between the attribute and
> the = sign.

Comment: I want the .php extension because I can use the counter script dynamically instead of creating a counter script for each choice.  If I don't use an extension of .php then I have to make a script for each choice and tell it the exact cookie name instead of allowing my $url=$_Get['url'] to dynamically change it for me.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but it sounds like a refactor might be in order here. Why do you need to store a PHP file name? You can use one PHP script, store a unique id in the cookie which references a row in a database table containing all the ancillary data. I really don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Okay, what I'm doing is setting a cookie and logging an ip in a database to allow users to only do an action once.  The main page for the logging a vote, includes a validation script which if it passes, includes a link script that sets the cookie and through onclick includes the clickcounter.php?url=...  This url is used dynamically to add to the database.  In the click counter I want to use the $_GET['url'] variable to put an if(isset($_COOKIE)) around the actual UPDATE sql code, which uses the $_GET['url'] to set the table field.  Otherwise, I'm going to have to do clickcounter1,2,3,4,ect

Comment: Like I say I think a re-think would be a good idea. Storing a file name doesn't make sense there are better ways to get around this problem.

Comment: If I didn't have to use the underscore, it would be perfect.  One script to add the count, log the ip, and verify that the cookie had been set to be used on as many entries as you wanted.  I'm definitely going to have to ponder it for a while now.. :P